# Screen goes black when playing games

Tags: 14.04, games, screen, steam

I'm having some problems recently when i play dota.
All is running fine for ~2hrs and than suddenly the screen goes blank, although i can hear sounds and that the system is running. Can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> fine, but when i try to get back into graphic with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> nothing happens, just a blinking underscore.
What could be the problem?

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution requires a custom kernel.

Comment: IIRC we don't close because of some answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is the graphic drivers. 
Since I'm on ubuntu 14.04 with HD Graphics 4000
I edit the `/etc/lsb-release` so the system looks like 14.10, so I can get the driver (because HD Graphics 4000 support Ubuntu 14.10 & 15.04). So I'll have to upgrade for real to 15.04 or wait for LTS and bare with this ugly problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the kernel to 4.3.3 fixes this issue.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" your own answer in 24 hours time.  **;-)** As 4.3.3 is a custom kernel, this also makes the Q&A off-topic here... **:-(**